# new line after creating label on code hehind

Tags: c#, html

I need to create a label and a text box near it, every time the user choose an option from the checkBoxList.
I'm doing this with this code:

```
            int count = 0;
            for (int l = 0; l < CheckBoxList1.Items.Count; l++)
                if (CheckBoxList1.Items[l].Selected)
                {
                    count++;
                    var check = new Label();
                    check.Text = "bla bla" + count.ToString();
                    check.ID = "bla bla" + count.ToString();
                    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(check);
                    TextBox TextBox1 = new TextBox();
                    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(TextBox1);
                }
```

and it looks like that:

[image]

what can I write to make it looks like:

`bla bla1 TextBox ***new line***
bla bla2 TextBox.`

Comment: I assume this is WinForms?

Comment: Which version of ASP.NET is this? MVC? Are you using Razor? What does your cshtml or markup look like? Or is this WinForms?

Comment: actually, i don't have any idea what you are talking about. it's just a project for school, i don't understand a lot about it

Comment: What technology are you using to make the UI? ASP.NET (it's a website), WinForms (it's an older-style desktop app)?

Comment: ASP.NET........